# CentOS release 6.9 (Final) appends twice

Tags: centos-6

I'm trying to append someting to a file

```
rm temp.upload
echo -n 'test' >> temp.upload
cat temp.upload
testtest
```

but anyhow it gets appended twice

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that the `rm` command is deleting the file?

Comment: yes i already tried another filename which not exists